# How to enable two finger scrolling without trackpad options?

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad

I just installed Katya (linux mint 11) on my new Dell Inspiron 15R, and in Windows, my mouse supports multitouch (two finger scroll, three finger swipe, etc.). I have checked `Preferences->Mouse` and there is supposed to be a `Touchpad`, or similar section, but there is no such section available. Sidescrolling works, but I am unable to find any trackpad/touchpad specific settings. Anyone have a solution?

**EDIT:** for clarification, i am dual booting Win7 and Mint in separate partitions on the same machine.

Comment: What is the trackpad manufacture? Synaptics? Alps? Have you installed specific xorg-input drivers for that manufacture?

Comment: `Alps Electric`, according to Windows Device Manager. Here might be the problem; the Device Manager reads that the touchpad is plugged into the PS2 mouse port. If Mint reads it the same way, this might explain why it thinks it's an external mouse...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the multitouch support and other touchpad specific input device features on Linux only work on USB, not PS2.

The touchpads in most new laptops are USB, but often the BIOS has an emulator mode to present the device as PS2 for compatibility with older OSes. You should look through your BIOS and turn off anything to do with emulating PS2 devices. Chances are when you boot up with the touchpad showing up as a USB device Linux will figure out what it is and give you some features for it.

Comment: i looked through the BIOS and couldn't find any option for PS2 vs. USB touchpad emulcation. Is there a way i could force Linux to think it's a USB device?

Comment: Only if it actually IS a USB device. Can you confirm that from the model / specs of your machine?

Comment: i found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1757679.html) for disabling the Alps touchpad, and they had the similar issue with no `trackpad` option in the mouse menu. But no options for two finger scrolling...

and i found [this](http://budts.be/weblog/2010/12/dell-latitude-e6510-screen-and-touchpad) article for scrolling on a latitude, but i'm not sure if this is the similar enough..